# German Census Demographic Data @ zip-code level

Tags: census, germany

The US Census has an API to pull Census/ACS data at the ZTCA (zip-code tabulation area) level. I'm looking for the same functionality with German data. So far I've identified several websites such as https://www-genesis.destatis.de, https://www.destatis.de/EN/Homepage.html and http://www.forschungsdatenzentrum.de/ for German demographic data, but they seem to go down to the "Gemeinde" and "Verbandsgemeinden" level, not the "Postleitzahl" level.

Also, data seems packaged in Tables, rather than extractable via APIs. I'm still going through the documentation.

Any pointers?

(BTW, http://www.programmableweb.com/api/genesis-online points to the urls above)

Comment: Difficult and in small info blocks ..you will need a web harvester for that. ..https://ergebnisse.zensus2011.de/#StaticContent:00,,,

Answer (score 0):

Information from zensus2011.de has been pre-processed and is available in CSV format from https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/downloads.